# Cannot run react native run-android

Tags: react-native, java-home

I have the next problem when i try to run react -native, i need to know how i can configurate the environment to make this works propery

this is my this is my environment [image]

```
Could not write standard input to Gradle build daemon.
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(java.base@9-internal/ProcessBuilder.java:443)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(java.base@9-internal/OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(java.base@9-internal/BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(java.base@9-internal/BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:67)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@9-internal/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1158)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@9-internal/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:632)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-internal/Thread.java:804)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /home/ale/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.4.1-all/3221gyojl5jsh0helicew7rwx/gradle-5.4.1/lib/gradle-launcher-5.4.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 5.4.1
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Unrecognized option: --add-opens
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 0):

check your package.json file in your project, it should contain an object like this

```
 "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
  }
```

then you can use react-native run-android or you need to use whatever the string given to android or you can edit that to whatever you want.

Comment: i have something like this


```"scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .jsx,.js,.tsx,.ts .",
    "codegen": "graphql-codegen"
  }, ```

Comment: any ideas, in fact thanks a lot for the quickly answer

Comment: inside scripts object you add     "android": "react-native run-android"   this , then try react-native run-android